# jquery replace square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to convert square brackets on a form submit. I won't go into the form submission part as it's not required.

I had no problem replacing a new line with a `<br />` tag like so:

```
new_line = message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

however what I'm trying to achieve now is convert `[b] [/b]` to `<strong> </strong>`. This is what I have tried so far but it doesn't seem to be working. I find regex's rather hard to grasp.

```
bold = message.replace(/\[b].*\[\/b]/g, '<strong>');
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one...

```
bold = message.replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
'[b]asdf[/b]'.replace(/\[(\/?)b\]/g, '<$1strong>')
```

Comment: Given invalid bbcode `[b]hello world[/b][/b][b]`, the above will result in invalid html that can corrupt the layout unexpectedly: `<strong>hello world</strong></strong><strong>`.